# rendering bitmaps using canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk, android-video-player

I was working on video player, where I get frames as bitmaps. Just wondering how can I stream the bitmaps continuously without using while loop. Are there any samples?

Comment: What do you mean by "stream bitmap"? What's wrong with the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `postInvalidate()` (or, to throttle the rendering to something reasonable, `postInvalidateDelayed()`) from within your `onDraw()` processing.

Comment: are there any sample code on it. I am unable to use them. Any help is greatly appreciated